# Blender animation is cut short in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, blender

I wasn't sure if this is the right site to ask, since this is more code based, but I thought at least one person may know. I have a blender walk cycle that is correct in blender, but is cut about 8 frames to short in unity. I have gone online every where to find the answer and all I found was one lonely man who asked on a unity forum 2 years ago and never recieved an answer. If I shouldnt ask this question here then let me know.

Ask if more details are needed, thank you!

Comment: How are you importing your model into Unity? With the .blend file? What version of Blender and Unity?

Comment: I used the .blend file and I am still on blender 2.78.

Comment: I would try exporting as .fbx out of Blender. It's my understanding that Unity doesn't have built in support for .blend files, it basically converts them to .fbx for you and it doesn't do as good of a job as Blender does. You can read about it on the [Unity site](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/3D-formats.html)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will try this and let you know when I can. Also 2.79 not 8. I don't know why I said that.